# How to allow UICollectionView to scroll in intervals of the cell width

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a UICollectionView that scrolls sideways. When it is scrolled I want it to land on a multiple of the cell width. The cells are diamonds and must fit in a very precise location.

Example: If user scrolls, then the scroll will happen as normal (or maybe semi-paged) and then when it stops, make sure it stops at a multiple so the cell can be aligned with the diamonds.

Any idea how to approach this?
[image]

Comment: See the accepted answer to this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13492037/targetcontentoffsetforproposedcontentoffsetwithscrollingvelocity-without-subcla