# Paging UICollectionView by cells, not screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have `UICollectionView` with horizontal scrolling and there are always 2 cells side-by-side per the entire screen. I need the scrolling to stop at the begining of a cell. With paging enabled, the collection view scrolls the whole page, which is 2 cells at once, and then it stops.

I need to enable scrolling by a single cell, or scrolling by multiple cells with stopping at the edge of the cell.

I tried to subclass `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` and to implement the method `targetContentOffsetForProposedContentOffset`, but so far I was only able to break my collection view and it stopped scrolling. Is there any easier way to achieve this and how, or do I really need to implement all methods of `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` subclass? Thanks.

Comment: your collectionviewcell width is must equal to screnn width and collectionView Paging enabled

Comment: But I need to show 2 cells at once. I am on iPad, so 2 cells share one half of the screen each.

Comment: Use `targetContentOffsetForProposedContentOffset:withScrollingVelocity:` and turn off paging

Comment: This is what I am trying. Any example somewhere?

Comment: @MohammadBashirSidani no, it doesn't

Comment: Ten yrs later, there's finally a trivial solution for this, see my answer for an explanation

Answer (score 50, accepted):

OK, so I found the solution here: [targetContentOffsetForProposedContentOffset:withScrollingVelocity without subclassing UICollectionViewFlowLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13492037/targetcontentoffsetforproposedcontentoffsetwithscrollingvelocity-without-subcla)

I should have searched for `targetContentOffsetForProposedContentOffset` in the begining.

Comment: for anyone asking about this in swift 5: collectionView.isPagingEnabled = true does this!

Comment: @Mohammad Bashir Sidani No I doesn't. Read the question.

Answer (score 28):

Here's my implementation in **Swift 5** for **vertical** cell-based paging:

```
override func targetContentOffset(forProposedContentOffset proposedContentOffset: CGPoint, withScrollingVelocity velocity: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {

    guard let collectionView = self.collectionView else {
        let latestOffset = super.targetContentOffset(forProposedContentOffset: proposedContentOffset, withScrollingVelocity: velocity)
        return latestOffset
    }

    // Page height used for estimating and calculating paging.
    let pageHeight = self.itemSize.height + self.minimumLineSpacing

    // Make an estimation of the current page position.
    let approximatePage = collectionView.contentOffset.y/pageHeight

    // Determine the current page based on velocity.
    let currentPage = velocity.y == 0 ? round(approximatePage) : (velocity.y < 0.0 ? floor(approximatePage) : ceil(approximatePage))

    // Create custom flickVelocity.
    let flickVelocity = velocity.y * 0.3

    // Check how many pages the user flicked, if <= 1 then flickedPages should return 0.
    let flickedPages = (abs(round(flickVelocity)) <= 1) ? 0 : round(flickVelocity)

    let newVerticalOffset = ((currentPage + flickedPages) * pageHeight) - collectionView.contentInset.top

    return CGPoint(x: proposedContentOffset.x, y: newVerticalOffset)
}
```

*Some notes:*

- **Doesn't glitch**
- **SET PAGING TO FALSE**! (otherwise this won't work)
- Allows you to set **your own flickvelocity** easily.
- If something is still not working after trying this, check if your `itemSize` actually matches the size of the item as that's often a problem, especially when using `collectionView(_:layout:sizeForItemAt:)`, use a custom variable with the itemSize instead.
- This works best when you set `self.collectionView.decelerationRate = UIScrollView.DecelerationRate.fast`.

Here's a **horizontal** version (haven't tested it thoroughly so please forgive any mistakes):

```
override func targetContentOffset(forProposedContentOffset proposedContentOffset: CGPoint, withScrollingVelocity velocity: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {

    guard let collectionView = self.collectionView else {
        let latestOffset = super.targetContentOffset(forProposedContentOffset: proposedContentOffset, withScrollingVelocity: velocity)
        return latestOffset
    }

    // Page width used for estimating and calculating paging.
    let pageWidth = self.itemSize.width + self.minimumInteritemSpacing

    // Make an estimation of the current page position.
    let approximatePage = collectionView.contentOffset.x/pageWidth

    // Determine the current page based on velocity.
    let currentPage = velocity.x == 0 ? round(approximatePage) : (velocity.x < 0.0 ? floor(approximatePage) : ceil(approximatePage))

    // Create custom flickVelocity.
    let flickVelocity = velocity.x * 0.3

    // Check how many pages the user flicked, if <= 1 then flickedPages should return 0.
    let flickedPages = (abs(round(flickVelocity)) <= 1) ? 0 : round(flickVelocity)

    // Calculate newHorizontalOffset.
    let newHorizontalOffset = ((currentPage + flickedPages) * pageWidth) - collectionView.contentInset.left

    return CGPoint(x: newHorizontalOffset, y: proposedContentOffset.y)
}
```

This code is based on the code I use in my personal project, you can check it out [here](https://github.com/JoniVR/VerticalCardSwiper) by downloading it and running the Example target.

Comment: For Swift 5: use `.fast` instead of `UIScollViewDecelerationRateFast`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! Forgot to update this answer and just did!

Comment: Hi, @JoniVR very nice explanation example to show how the swiping will work vertically. It will be very kind of you to suggest what overall code changes needed for making this work flawlessly in a horizontal direction. Apart from the code above you suggested for the horizontal swiping in target content offset function. I think there are a lot of changes to made to replicate the exact scenario horizontally. Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 24):

just override the method:

```
- (void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset {
    *targetContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset; // set acceleration to 0.0
    float pageWidth = (float)self.articlesCollectionView.bounds.size.width;
    int minSpace = 10;

    int cellToSwipe = (scrollView.contentOffset.x)/(pageWidth + minSpace) + 0.5; // cell width + min spacing for lines
    if (cellToSwipe < 0) {
        cellToSwipe = 0;
    } else if (cellToSwipe >= self.articles.count) {
        cellToSwipe = self.articles.count - 1;
    }
    [self.articlesCollectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:cellToSwipe inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionLeft animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: That piece of code helped me a lot, I had to add the check for the current scrolling direction though and accordingly adapted the +/- 0.5 value.

Comment: You can set collectionView.pagingEnabled = true

Comment: @evya Wow you're right.  isPagingEnabled worked for me.

Comment: @evya great stuff!!

Comment: How is pagingEnabled working for you guys? Mine gets super glitchy before ending up at the original paging offset

Answer (score 18):

### Horizontal Paging With Custom Page Width (Swift 4 & 5)

Many solutions presented here result in some weird behaviour that doesn't feel like properly implemented paging.

---

The solution presented in [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@shaibalassiano/tutorial-horizontal-uicollectionview-with-paging-9421b479ee94), however, doesn't seem to have any issues. It just feels like a perfectly  working paging algorithm. You can implement it in 5 simple steps:

1. Add the following property to your type: `private var indexOfCellBeforeDragging = 0`
2. Set the `collectionView` `delegate` like this: `collectionView.delegate = self`
3. Add conformance to `UICollectionViewDelegate` via an extension: `extension YourType: UICollectionViewDelegate { }`
4. Add the following method to the extension implementing the `UICollectionViewDelegate` conformance and set a value for `pageWidth`:

   ```
   func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
       let pageWidth = // The width your page should have (plus a possible margin)
       let proportionalOffset = collectionView.contentOffset.x / pageWidth
       indexOfCellBeforeDragging = Int(round(proportionalOffset))
   }
   ```
5. Add the following method to the extension implementing the `UICollectionViewDelegate` conformance, set the same value for `pageWidth` (you may also store this value at a central place) and set a value for `collectionViewItemCount`:

   ```
   func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {
       // Stop scrolling
       targetContentOffset.pointee = scrollView.contentOffset

       // Calculate conditions
       let pageWidth = // The width your page should have (plus a possible margin)
       let collectionViewItemCount = // The number of items in this section
       let proportionalOffset = collectionView.contentOffset.x / pageWidth
       let indexOfMajorCell = Int(round(proportionalOffset))
       let swipeVelocityThreshold: CGFloat = 0.5
       let hasEnoughVelocityToSlideToTheNextCell = indexOfCellBeforeDragging + 1 < collectionViewItemCount && velocity.x > swipeVelocityThreshold
       let hasEnoughVelocityToSlideToThePreviousCell = indexOfCellBeforeDragging - 1 >= 0 && velocity.x < -swipeVelocityThreshold
       let majorCellIsTheCellBeforeDragging = indexOfMajorCell == indexOfCellBeforeDragging
       let didUseSwipeToSkipCell = majorCellIsTheCellBeforeDragging && (hasEnoughVelocityToSlideToTheNextCell || hasEnoughVelocityToSlideToThePreviousCell)

       if didUseSwipeToSkipCell {
           // Animate so that swipe is just continued
           let snapToIndex = indexOfCellBeforeDragging + (hasEnoughVelocityToSlideToTheNextCell ? 1 : -1)
           let toValue = pageWidth * CGFloat(snapToIndex)
           UIView.animate(
               withDuration: 0.3,
               delay: 0,
               usingSpringWithDamping: 1,
               initialSpringVelocity: velocity.x,
               options: .allowUserInteraction,
               animations: {
                   scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: toValue, y: 0)
                   scrollView.layoutIfNeeded()
               },
               completion: nil
           )
       } else {
           // Pop back (against velocity)
           let indexPath = IndexPath(row: indexOfMajorCell, section: 0)
           collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .left, animated: true)
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: For anybody using this you need to change the `Pop back (against velocity)` part to be:

`collectionViewLayout.collectionView!.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)`.

Note the `.centeredHorizontally`

Comment: @matthew.kempson Depends on how you want the layout to behave. For the layout I used this with, `.left` was fine

Comment: I found that `.left` didn't work as expected. It seemed to push the cell too far back @fredpi

Answer (score 17):

Here's the easiest way that i found to do that in **Swift 4.2** for **horinzontal** scroll:

I'm using the first cell on **`visibleCells`** and scrolling to then, if the first visible cell are showing less of the half of it's width i'm scrolling to the next one.

If your collection scroll **vertically**, simply change `x` by `y` and `width` by `height`

```
func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {
    targetContentOffset.pointee = scrollView.contentOffset
    var indexes = self.collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems
    indexes.sort()
    var index = indexes.first!
    let cell = self.collectionView.cellForItem(at: index)!
    let position = self.collectionView.contentOffset.x - cell.frame.origin.x
    if position > cell.frame.size.width/2{
       index.row = index.row+1
    }
    self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: index, at: .left, animated: true )
}
```

Comment: Can you please add the link to the source article. Great Answer BTW.

Comment: @Md.IbrahimHassan There is no article, i'm the source. Thx

Comment: it works, but unfortunately the experience is not smooth

Comment: What do you mean with not smooth?

For me, the result is animated very smooth..
See my result [here](https://gph.is/2RSkVJa)

Comment: If your collection view uses sections then this implementation can cause a crash. You can reach an out of bounds index by increasing the row to greater than the number of items in that section. But overall I like this solution, just adding it as a comment here

Answer (score 13):

Swift 3 version of Evya's answer:

```
func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {
  targetContentOffset.pointee = scrollView.contentOffset
    let pageWidth:Float = Float(self.view.bounds.width)
    let minSpace:Float = 10.0
    var cellToSwipe:Double = Double(Float((scrollView.contentOffset.x))/Float((pageWidth+minSpace))) + Double(0.5)
    if cellToSwipe < 0 {
        cellToSwipe = 0
    } else if cellToSwipe >= Double(self.articles.count) {
        cellToSwipe = Double(self.articles.count) - Double(1)
    }
    let indexPath:IndexPath = IndexPath(row: Int(cellToSwipe), section:0)
    self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at:indexPath, at: UICollectionViewScrollPosition.left, animated: true)


}
```

Comment: When you click on the side of the cell, the there is a weird offset

Comment: Hey @Maor, I don't know if you still need it, but in my case that was fixed disabling paging on the collection view.

Comment: I loved this but felt a little sluggish with quick small swipes, so I added something to take velocity into account and makes it much smoother: 
`if(velocity.x > 1) {
            mod = 0.5;
        } else if(velocity.x < -1) {
            mod = -0.5;
        }`
then add `+ mod` after the `+ Double(0.5)`

Answer (score 9):

Partly based on StevenOjo's answer.
I've tested this using a horizontal scrolling and no Bounce UICollectionView. cellSize is CollectionViewCell size. You can tweak factor to modify scrolling sensitivity.

```
override func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {
    targetContentOffset.pointee = scrollView.contentOffset
    var factor: CGFloat = 0.5
    if velocity.x < 0 {
        factor = -factor
    }
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: (scrollView.contentOffset.x/cellSize.width + factor).int, section: 0)
    collectionView?.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .left, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 9):

**Here is the optimised solution in Swift5, including handling the wrong indexPath.** - Michael Lin Liu

- Step1. Get the indexPath of the current cell.
- Step2. Detect the velocity when scroll.
- Step3. Increase the indexPath's row when the velocity is increased.
- Step4. Tell the collection view to scroll to the next item

```
    func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {
        
        targetContentOffset.pointee = scrollView.contentOffset
        
        //M: Get the first visiable item's indexPath from visibaleItems.
        var indexPaths = *YOURCOLLECTIONVIEW*.indexPathsForVisibleItems
        indexPaths.sort()
        var indexPath = indexPaths.first!

        //M: Use the velocity to detect the paging control movement.
        //M: If the movement is forward, then increase the indexPath.
        if velocity.x > 0{
            indexPath.row += 1
            
            //M: If the movement is in the next section, which means the indexPath's row is out range. We set the indexPath to the first row of the next section.
            if indexPath.row == *YOURCOLLECTIONVIEW*.numberOfItems(inSection: indexPath.section){
                indexPath.row = 0
                indexPath.section += 1
            }
        }
        else{
            //M: If the movement is backward, the indexPath will be automatically changed to the first visiable item which is indexPath.row - 1. So there is no need to write the logic.
        }
        
        //M: Tell the collection view to scroll to the next item.
        *YOURCOLLECTIONVIEW*.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .left, animated: true )
 }
```

Comment: Readers should be aware that all such solutions are extremely rough. The physics behavior is completely wrong. Unfortunately!

Answer (score 8):

## Approach 1: Collection View

`flowLayout` is `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` property

```
override func scrollViewWillEndDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {

    if let collectionView = collectionView {

        targetContentOffset.memory = scrollView.contentOffset
        let pageWidth = CGRectGetWidth(scrollView.frame) + flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing

        var assistanceOffset : CGFloat = pageWidth / 3.0

        if velocity.x < 0 {
            assistanceOffset = -assistanceOffset
        }

        let assistedScrollPosition = (scrollView.contentOffset.x + assistanceOffset) / pageWidth

        var targetIndex = Int(round(assistedScrollPosition))


        if targetIndex < 0 {
            targetIndex = 0
        }
        else if targetIndex >= collectionView.numberOfItemsInSection(0) {
            targetIndex = collectionView.numberOfItemsInSection(0) - 1
        }

        print("targetIndex = \(targetIndex)")

        let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forItem: targetIndex, inSection: 0)

        collectionView.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(indexPath, atScrollPosition: .Left, animated: true)
    }
}
```

## Approach 2: Page View Controller

You could use `UIPageViewController` if it meets your requirements, each page would have a separate view controller.

Comment: For this I have to disable paging and enable scrolling only in collectionview?

Comment: This is not working for the latest swift4/Xcode9.3, targetContentOffset does not have a memory field. I implemented the scrolling but it is not adjusting the cell location when you "flick".

Comment: Works with a few cells but when I get to cell 13 it starts jumping back to the previous cell and you cannot continue.

Answer (score 6):

This is a straight way to do this.

The case is simple, but finally quite common ( typical thumbnails scroller with fixed cell size and fixed gap between cells )

```
var itemCellSize: CGSize = <your cell size>
var itemCellsGap: CGFloat = <gap in between>

override func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {
    let pageWidth = (itemCellSize.width + itemCellsGap)
    let itemIndex = (targetContentOffset.pointee.x) / pageWidth
    targetContentOffset.pointee.x = round(itemIndex) * pageWidth - (itemCellsGap / 2)
}

// CollectionViewFlowLayoutDelegate

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return itemCellSize
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return itemCellsGap
}
```

Note that there is no reason to call a scrollToOffset or dive into layouts.
The native scrolling behaviour already does everything.

Cheers All :)

Comment: You can optionally set `collectionView.decelerationRate = .fast` to closer mimmic default paging.

Comment: This is really nice. @elfanek I've found that setting that works ok unless you do a small & gentle swipe then it just seems to flicker quickly.

Answer (score 6):

modify Romulo BM answer for velocity listening

```
func scrollViewWillEndDragging(
    _ scrollView: UIScrollView,
    withVelocity velocity: CGPoint,
    targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>
) {
    targetContentOffset.pointee = scrollView.contentOffset
    var indexes = collection.indexPathsForVisibleItems
    indexes.sort()
    var index = indexes.first!
    if velocity.x > 0 {
       index.row += 1
    } else if velocity.x == 0 {
        let cell = self.collection.cellForItem(at: index)!
        let position = self.collection.contentOffset.x - cell.frame.origin.x
        if position > cell.frame.size.width / 2 {
           index.row += 1
        }
    }

    self.collection.scrollToItem(at: index, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true )
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Kind of like evya's answer, but a little smoother because it doesn't set the targetContentOffset to zero.

```
- (void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset {
    if ([scrollView isKindOfClass:[UICollectionView class]]) {
        UICollectionView* collectionView = (UICollectionView*)scrollView;
        if ([collectionView.collectionViewLayout isKindOfClass:[UICollectionViewFlowLayout class]]) {
            UICollectionViewFlowLayout* layout = (UICollectionViewFlowLayout*)collectionView.collectionViewLayout;

            CGFloat pageWidth = layout.itemSize.width + layout.minimumInteritemSpacing;
            CGFloat usualSideOverhang = (scrollView.bounds.size.width - pageWidth)/2.0;
            // k*pageWidth - usualSideOverhang = contentOffset for page at index k if k >= 1, 0 if k = 0
            // -> (contentOffset + usualSideOverhang)/pageWidth = k at page stops

            NSInteger targetPage = 0;
            CGFloat currentOffsetInPages = (scrollView.contentOffset.x + usualSideOverhang)/pageWidth;
            targetPage = velocity.x < 0 ? floor(currentOffsetInPages) : ceil(currentOffsetInPages);
            targetPage = MAX(0,MIN(self.projects.count - 1,targetPage));

            *targetContentOffset = CGPointMake(MAX(targetPage*pageWidth - usualSideOverhang,0), 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my version of it in Swift 3. Calculate the offset after scrolling ended and adjust the offset with animation.

`collectionLayout` is a  `UICollectionViewFlowLayout()`

```
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let index = scrollView.contentOffset.x / collectionLayout.itemSize.width
    let fracPart = index.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 1)
    let item= Int(fracPart >= 0.5 ? ceil(index) : floor(index))

    let indexPath = IndexPath(item: item, section: 0)
    collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .left, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 5**

I've found a way to do this without subclassing UICollectionView, just calculating the contentOffset in horizontal. Obviously without isPagingEnabled set true.
Here is the code:

```
var offsetScroll1 : CGFloat = 0
var offsetScroll2 : CGFloat = 0
let flowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
let screenSize : CGSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.size
var items = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    flowLayout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
    flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 7
    let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 590, width: screenSize.width, height: 200), collectionViewLayout: flowLayout)
    collectionView.register(collectionViewCell1.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier)
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    collectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    self.view.addSubview(collectionView)
}

func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    offsetScroll1 = offsetScroll2
}

func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
    offsetScroll1 = offsetScroll2
}

func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>){
    let indexOfMajorCell = self.desiredIndex()
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: indexOfMajorCell, section: 0)
    flowLayout.collectionView!.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
    targetContentOffset.pointee = scrollView.contentOffset
}

private func desiredIndex() -> Int {
    var integerIndex = 0
    print(flowLayout.collectionView!.contentOffset.x)
    offsetScroll2 = flowLayout.collectionView!.contentOffset.x
    if offsetScroll2 > offsetScroll1 {
        integerIndex += 1
        let offset = flowLayout.collectionView!.contentOffset.x / screenSize.width
        integerIndex = Int(round(offset))
        if integerIndex < (items.count - 1) {
            integerIndex += 1
        }
    }
    if offsetScroll2 < offsetScroll1 {
        let offset = flowLayout.collectionView!.contentOffset.x / screenSize.width
        integerIndex = Int(offset.rounded(.towardZero))
    }
    let targetIndex = integerIndex
    return targetIndex
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The original answer of Олень Безрогий had an issue, so on the last cell collection view was scrolling to the beginning

```
func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {
    targetContentOffset.pointee = scrollView.contentOffset
    var indexes = yourCollectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems
    indexes.sort()
    var index = indexes.first!
    // if velocity.x > 0 && (Get the number of items from your data) > index.row + 1 {
    if velocity.x > 0 && yourCollectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: 0) > index.row + 1 {
       index.row += 1
    } else if velocity.x == 0 {
        let cell = yourCollectionView.cellForItem(at: index)!
        let position = yourCollectionView.contentOffset.x - cell.frame.origin.x
        if position > cell.frame.size.width / 2 {
           index.row += 1
        }
    }
    
    yourCollectionView.scrollToItem(at: index, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Also you can create fake scroll view to handle scrolling.

Horizontal or Vertical

```
// === Defaults ===
let bannerSize = CGSize(width: 280, height: 170)
let pageWidth: CGFloat = 290 // ^ + paging
let insetLeft: CGFloat = 20
let insetRight: CGFloat = 20
// ================

var pageScrollView: UIScrollView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Create fake scrollview to properly handle paging
    pageScrollView = UIScrollView(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: pageWidth, height: 100)))
    pageScrollView.isPagingEnabled = true
    pageScrollView.alwaysBounceHorizontal = true
    pageScrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
    pageScrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    pageScrollView.delegate = self
    pageScrollView.isHidden = true
    view.insertSubview(pageScrollView, belowSubview: collectionView)

    // Set desired gesture recognizers to the collection view
    for gr in pageScrollView.gestureRecognizers! {
        collectionView.addGestureRecognizer(gr)
    }
}

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollView == pageScrollView {
        // Return scrolling back to the collection view
        collectionView.contentOffset.x = pageScrollView.contentOffset.x
    }
}

func refreshData() {
    ...

    refreshScroll()
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    refreshScroll()
}

/// Refresh fake scrolling view content size if content changes
func refreshScroll() {
    let w = collectionView.width - bannerSize.width - insetLeft - insetRight
    pageScrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: pageWidth * CGFloat(banners.count) - w, height: 100)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution, in Swift 4.2, I wish it could help you.

```swift
class SomeViewController: UIViewController {

  private lazy var flowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: /* width */, height: /* height */)
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = // margin
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0.0
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, left: /* margin */, bottom: 0.0, right: /* margin */)
    layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
    return layout
  }()

  private lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
    let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: flowLayout)
    collectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.delegate = self
    // collectionView.register(SomeCell.self)
    return collectionView
  }()

  private var currentIndex: Int = 0
}

// MARK: - UIScrollViewDelegate

extension SomeViewController {
  func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    guard scrollView == collectionView else { return }

    let pageWidth = flowLayout.itemSize.width + flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing
    currentIndex = Int(scrollView.contentOffset.x / pageWidth)
  }

  func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {
    guard scrollView == collectionView else { return }

    let pageWidth = flowLayout.itemSize.width + flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing
    var targetIndex = Int(roundf(Float(targetContentOffset.pointee.x / pageWidth)))
    if targetIndex > currentIndex {
      targetIndex = currentIndex + 1
    } else if targetIndex < currentIndex {
      targetIndex = currentIndex - 1
    }
    let count = collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: 0)
    targetIndex = max(min(targetIndex, count - 1), 0)
    print("targetIndex: \(targetIndex)")

    targetContentOffset.pointee = scrollView.contentOffset
    var offsetX: CGFloat = 0.0
    if targetIndex < count - 1 {
      offsetX = pageWidth * CGFloat(targetIndex)
    } else {
      offsetX = scrollView.contentSize.width - scrollView.width
    }
    collectionView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: offsetX, y: 0.0), animated: true)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The only **truly solid solution I have ever found** is this:

##### You actually use TWO collection views ...

1. Have your "visual" collection view. Which has the actual images in each cell. The visual collection view is the full width of the screen.
2. **On top of that**, i.e. directly above it, have you "touch" or "ghost" collection view. The **cells** are the **same** size, but the **width** of the touch collection view is **actually only the width of your "real" cells** in the "visual" collection view underneath.

The user only ever touches the "ghost" cv on top. And the ghost cv simply moves the "visual" cv.

It's actually remarkably easy to do this once you start setting it up.

All you need is one line of code to drive the underneath "visual" cv from the "ghost" cv, like

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    
    if scrollView == ghost {
        
        // double trouble magic:
        visual.contentOffset.x = ghost.contentOffset.x
    }
}
```

(Note that, more specifically, that line will be something like `visual.contentOffset.x = ghost.contentOffset.x - visual.contentInset.left` depending on your own style for setting up the two CVs.)

Once you try this approach, you'll never do it any other way, because it's absolutely rock solid, it literally works exactly as it should - since you're literally using a CV (the top one) that simply is "exactly the mechanism you want", by definition, no ifs ands or buts. It pages to the width of your cells, using obviously exactly the Apple physics/touch and that's that.

Obviously, the top "ghost" one simply has .. blank cells, ie just clear cells.

Incredibly, you just use the same data source for both !! Simply point both CVs at the same view controller for the `numberOfItemsInSection` and `cellForItemAt` calls!

Give it a try!

Once again, the whole thing is one line of code, given above.

If you think about it, the top "touch" one, the actual CV is as we say only as wide as one of your cells ... however, you want to be able to touch the top "touch" one anywhere on the full width of the screen. Of course, widening the touch area on any view is a very common issue you are familiar with, just use the usual solution, something like ...

```
class SuperWideCollectionView: UICollectionView {
    override func point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool { return bounds.insetBy(dx: -5000, dy: 0).contains(point) }
}
```

It's a great rig, and now the only way we do this.

This is one of the three or four Apple issues where it is "just incredible" they don't have a built in toggle in the relevant views where you can page by "item, not screen width" - but for now they don't!

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the proposed answers did'nt worked for me because I wanted to scroll by sections instead, and thus, have variable width page sizes

I did this (vertical only):

```
   var pagesSizes = [CGSize]()
   func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        defer {
            lastOffsetY = scrollView.contentOffset.y
        }
        if collectionView.isDecelerating {
            var currentPage = 0
            var currentPageBottom = CGFloat(0)
            for pagesSize in pagesSizes {
                currentPageBottom += pagesSize.height
                if currentPageBottom > collectionView!.contentOffset.y {
                    break
                }
                currentPage += 1
            }
            if collectionView.contentOffset.y > currentPageBottom - pagesSizes[currentPage].height, collectionView.contentOffset.y + collectionView.frame.height < currentPageBottom {
                return // 100% of view within bounds
            }
            if lastOffsetY < collectionView.contentOffset.y {
                if currentPage + 1 != pagesSizes.count {
                    collectionView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: currentPageBottom), animated: true)
                }
            } else {
                collectionView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: currentPageBottom - pagesSizes[currentPage].height), animated: true)
            }
        }
    }
```

In this case, I calculate each page size beforehand using the section height + header + footer, and store it in the array. That's the `pagesSizes` member

Answer (score 0):

i created a custom collection view layout [here](https://github.com/akxo/paging-collection-view-layout) that supports:

- paging one cell at a time
- paging 2+ cells at a time depending on swipe velocity
- horizontal or vertical directions

it's as easy as:

```
let layout = PagingCollectionViewLayout()

layout.itemSize = 
layout.minimumLineSpacing = 
layout.scrollDirection =
```

you can just add [PagingCollectionViewLayout.swift](https://github.com/akxo/paging-collection-view-layout/blob/master/PagingCollectionViewLayout.swift) to your project

or

add `pod 'PagingCollectionViewLayout'` to your podfile

Comment: well it works but not sure why it worked only for cell height 600 for me in vertical scrolling collection view. Tried other height values but it would either scroll more or less than the item.

Answer (score 0):

```
final class PagingFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
    private var currentIndex = 0

    override func targetContentOffset(forProposedContentOffset proposedContentOffset: CGPoint, withScrollingVelocity velocity: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
        let count = collectionView!.numberOfItems(inSection: 0)
        let currentAttribute = layoutAttributesForItem(
            at: IndexPath(item: currentIndex, section: 0)
            ) ?? UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes()

        let direction = proposedContentOffset.x > currentAttribute.frame.minX
        if collectionView!.contentOffset.x + collectionView!.bounds.width < collectionView!.contentSize.width || currentIndex < count - 1 {
            currentIndex += direction ? 1 : -1
            currentIndex = max(min(currentIndex, count - 1), 0)
        }

        let indexPath = IndexPath(item: currentIndex, section: 0)
        let closestAttribute = layoutAttributesForItem(at: indexPath) ?? UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes()

        let centerOffset = collectionView!.bounds.size.width / 2
        return CGPoint(x: closestAttribute.center.x - centerOffset, y: 0)
    }
}
```

Comment: You should not copy/paste answers. Mark it as duplicate if appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

It is the best solution I ever seen. Just use it with `.linear` type.
https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel
God bless the author!:)

Answer (score -1):

Here is my way to do it by using a `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` to override the `targetContentOffset`:

(Although in the end, I end up not using this and use UIPageViewController instead.)

```
/**
 A UICollectionViewFlowLayout with...
 - paged horizontal scrolling
 - itemSize is the same as the collectionView bounds.size
 */
class PagedFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

  override init() {
    super.init()
    self.scrollDirection = .horizontal
    self.minimumLineSpacing = 8 // line spacing is the horizontal spacing in horizontal scrollDirection
    self.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
      self.sectionInsetReference = .fromSafeArea // for iPhone X
    }
  }

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("not implemented")
  }

  // Note: Setting `minimumInteritemSpacing` here will be too late. Don't do it here.
  override func prepare() {
    super.prepare()
    guard let collectionView = collectionView else { return }
    collectionView.decelerationRate = UIScrollViewDecelerationRateFast // mostly you want it fast!

    let insetedBounds = UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(collectionView.bounds, self.sectionInset)
    self.itemSize = insetedBounds.size
  }

  // Table: Possible cases of targetContentOffset calculation
  // -------------------------
  // start |          |
  // near  | velocity | end
  // page  |          | page
  // -------------------------
  //   0   | forward  |  1
  //   0   | still    |  0
  //   0   | backward |  0
  //   1   | forward  |  1
  //   1   | still    |  1
  //   1   | backward |  0
  // -------------------------
  override func targetContentOffset( //swiftlint:disable:this cyclomatic_complexity
    forProposedContentOffset proposedContentOffset: CGPoint, withScrollingVelocity velocity: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {

    guard let collectionView = collectionView else { return proposedContentOffset }

    let pageWidth = itemSize.width + minimumLineSpacing
    let currentPage: CGFloat = collectionView.contentOffset.x / pageWidth
    let nearestPage: CGFloat = round(currentPage)
    let isNearPreviousPage = nearestPage < currentPage

    var pageDiff: CGFloat = 0
    let velocityThreshold: CGFloat = 0.5 // can customize this threshold
    if isNearPreviousPage {
      if velocity.x > velocityThreshold {
        pageDiff = 1
      }
    } else {
      if velocity.x < -velocityThreshold {
        pageDiff = -1
      }
    }

    let x = (nearestPage + pageDiff) * pageWidth
    let cappedX = max(0, x) // cap to avoid targeting beyond content
    //print("x:", x, "velocity:", velocity)
    return CGPoint(x: cappedX, y: proposedContentOffset.y)
  }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following library: https://github.com/ink-spot/UPCarouselFlowLayout

It's very simple and ofc you do not need to think about details like other answers contain.

Answer (score -1):

```
func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity 
velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {
    targetContentOffset.pointee = scrollView.contentOffset
    var indexes = self.collectionHome.indexPathsForVisibleItems
    indexes.sort()
    var index = indexes.first!
    let cell = self.collectionHome.cellForItem(at: index)!
    let position = self.collectionHome.contentOffset.x - cell.frame.origin.x
    if position > cell.frame.size.width/2{
        index.row = index.row+1
    }
    self.collectionHome.scrollToItem(at: index, at: .left, animated: true )
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.