# Centred Paging for CollectionView cells in iOS Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview

I created a table view that has collection view inside its cells with this tutorial [Creating a Scrolling Filmstrip Within a UITableView](http://devblog.orgsync.com/2013/04/26/creating_scrolling_filmstrip_within_uitableview/) but I want to achieve a banner kind of feature that has centred paging and scrolls automatically to each cell item. I enabled page scrolling but didn't work. How do I do this? I currently have a UIView in the table view cell that serves as the data source for the collection view. Here is the code for the UIView subclass.

```
@interface ContainerCellView () <UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UICollectionView *collectionView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *collectionData;
@end

@implementation ContainerCellView

#pragma mark - Getter/Setter ovverides
- (void)setCollectionData:(NSArray *)collectionData {
_collectionData = collectionData;
[_collectionView setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:YES];
[_collectionView reloadData];
} 

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
return 1;
}

 - (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return [self.collectionData count];
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ArticleCollectionViewCell";
BannersCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
NSDictionary *cellData = [self.collectionData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.articleTitle.text = [cellData objectForKey:@"title"];
return cell;
 }

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
NSDictionary *cellData = [self.collectionData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"didSelectItemFromCollectionView" object:cellData];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

You are possibly looking for property for collectionView called `isPagingEnabled` which comes from `UIScrollView`, otherwise, you should create your cell big enough to achieve this pretty nice effect. 
 However, you can relate here, if you are looking for paging by cells [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22895465/paging-uicollectionview-by-cells-not-screen) 
 
 Hope this may help you