# Card swapping by using collection view

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, autolayout

How can I make the design by using collection view, please explain me. Here is the image of the design:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is simply a `UICollectionView` with a `UIPageControl` below it.

You just need to design a `UICollectionViewCell` that looks like a card and use that in your collection view.

Have a look at [this Ray Wenderlich tutorial] to give you an idea how to use a `UICollectionView`. Of course you'll need a horizontal scrolling one, but that's easy configurable. Also read the [iOS documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview).

You'll also need to scrolling to stop with one full card visible; [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22895465/1971013).

Since you're new on StackOverflow you may not know this: On StackOverflow you're expected to first do your own research and try hard to get something working. Then when you have a detailed issue you can't figure out, you post that here. Please do so next time.

Comment: Pardon me, but isn't it UIScrollView + UIPageControl?

Comment: @ElTomato `UICollectionView` is a direct subclass of `UIScrollView` that adds functionality you'd have to write yourself if you start with a plain `UIScrollView`.