# Swift - Paging UICollectionView by cell while keeping the cell horizontally centered

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uipickerview, scroll-paging

First, not sure if the title is correct or offers the best description but I'm not sure what else to use.

So, i'm working on an app and I reached a section where I got stuck while implementing the UI.
Basically, I have a VC (image below) that can segue to its self based on the info I get from a JSON file.

[image]

The thing is I need to have a carousel-like menu in the upper side with an undefined number of cells (again, depends on what I get from the JSON file).
I decided to go for a UICollectionView for this and I managed to implement the basics without any problem.

But here is the part where I got stuck:

1. Since the selected cell must ALWAYS be centered, when the first and the last cell gets selected, I need to have an empty space between the cell and the safe area (see the image above).
2. The scroll needs to be paged. Normally this wouldn't be a problem if the UICollectionView cell would have a width almost equal to the one of the screen but the requirement is to be able to scroll one element at a time (see second screen above).

I tried finding something similar but maybe I'm not looking for the right thing because all I could find was [Paging UICollectionView by cells, not screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22895465/paging-uicollectionview-by-cells-not-screen)

Also, to be honest I've never seen an app / UICollectionView with this behaviour.

I posted parts of the code below but it's not really gonna help much since it's just standard UICollectionView methods.

Any suggestions?

```
class PreSignupDataVC : UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource

@IBOutlet weak var cvQuestions: UICollectionView!

var questionCell : PreSignupDataQuestionCellVC!
var screenData : Array<PreSignupScreenData> = Array<PreSignupScreenData>()
var pvDataSource : [String] = []
var numberOfComponents : Int = 0
var numberOfRowsInComponent : Int = 0
var currentScreen : Int = 1
var selectedType : Int?
var selectedCell : Int = 0
var initialLastCellInsetPoint : CGFloat = 0.0

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    print("PreSignupDataVC > viewDidLoad")

    initialLastCellInsetPoint = (self.view.frame.width - 170)/2
    screenData = DataSingleton.sharedInstance.returnPreSignUpUIArray()[selectedType!].screenData
    numberOfComponents = screenData[currentScreen - 1].controls[0].numberOfComponents!
    numberOfRowsInComponent = screenData[currentScreen - 1].controls[0].controlDataSource.count
    pvDataSource = screenData[currentScreen - 1].controls[0].controlDataSource

    cvQuestions.register(UINib(nibName: "PreSignupDataQuestionCell",
                               bundle: nil),
                         forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "PreSignupDataQuestionCellVC")
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    print("PreSignupDataVC > collectionView > numberOfItemsInSection")

    return screenData[currentScreen - 1].controls.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{
    print("PreSignupDataVC > collectionView > cellForItemAt")

    questionCell = (cvQuestions.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "PreSignupDataQuestionCellVC",
                                                    for: indexPath) as? PreSignupDataQuestionCellVC)!
    questionCell.vQuestionCellCellContainer.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0
    questionCell.lblQuestion.text = screenData[currentScreen - 1].controls[indexPath.row].cellTitle
    questionCell.ivQuestionCellImage.image = UIImage(named: screenData[currentScreen - 1].controls[indexPath.row].cellUnselectedIcon!)

    return questionCell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    print("PreSignupDataVC > collectionView > didSelectItemAt")

    numberOfComponents = screenData[currentScreen - 1].controls[indexPath.row].numberOfComponents!
    numberOfRowsInComponent = screenData[currentScreen - 1].controls[indexPath.row].controlDataSource.count
    pvDataSource = screenData[currentScreen - 1].controls[indexPath.row].controlDataSource
    selectedCell = indexPath.row

    pvData.reloadAllComponents()
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets
{
    print("PreSignupDataVC > collectionView > insetForSectionAt")

    return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, left: initialLastCellInsetPoint, bottom: 00.0, right: initialLastCellInsetPoint)
}
```

Comment: For immediate solution, you can use iCarousel animation. You can get it from Google.

Comment: You would never use a library for such a simple problem.  The immediate instant answer to you question is just to set the content insets (the "empty wings") on the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>You can use `insetForSectionAtIndex` to add spacing at first and last cell</strike>


**UPDATE**
You can use scroll view.
First: add leading and trailing to scroll view:
[image]

Second: `scrollView.clipsToBounds = false`
Third: add view to scroll view

```
func setupScrollView() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.scrollView.layoutIfNeeded() // in order to get correct frame

        let numberItem = 6
        let spaceBetweenView: CGFloat = 20
        let firstAndLastSpace: CGFloat = spaceBetweenView / 2            
        let width = self.scrollView.frame.size.width
        let height = self.scrollView.frame.size.height
        let numberOfView: CGFloat = CGFloat(numberItem)
        let scrollViewContentSizeWidth = numberOfView * width

        self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: scrollViewContentSizeWidth, height: height)

        for index in 0..<numberItem {
            let xCoordinate = (CGFloat(index) * (width)) + firstAndLastSpace
            let viewFrame = CGRect(x: xCoordinate, y: 0, width: width - spaceBetweenView, height: height)
            let view = UIView()
            view.backgroundColor = .red

            view.frame = viewFrame
            self.scrollView.addSubview(view)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This solved the inset part. I updated the code with the latest changes.

Comment: @daydr3am3r Sorry i was not read all your question. I've updated answer.

Comment: Thanks. It works. However, I do get a warning even though I added the exact constraints as you did. "Scrollable content size is ambiguous for ScrollView". In fact, no matter what I tried, I still got the same warning. Any ideas? Also, I am having some issues with attaching UITapGestureRecognizer to each of the views inside the scrollView, based on the view's tag.

Comment: For tap gesture, view can add itself and send callback to vc. And vc will handle it by model or something you pass to view.

Comment: Hi. I fixed the constraint problem by placing the ScrollView inside an UIView. I also made a few changes to make it look OK and to tap on each UIView - https://pastebin.com/4EcjeNqH Thanks.

Comment: You should remove `+ lastSpace` in `xCoordinate`

Comment: Thanks. I did. Forgot to remove it after I set it to 0.0.

Answer (score 11):

### #1. Using `UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout` (requires iOS 13)

Since iOS 13, you can use [`UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewcompositionallayout) and set [`NSCollectionLayoutSection`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nscollectionlayoutsection)'s [`orthogonalScrollingBehavior`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nscollectionlayoutsection/3199094-orthogonalscrollingbehavior) property to [`.groupPagingCentered`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionlayoutsectionorthogonalscrollingbehavior/grouppagingcentered) in order to have a centered horizontal carousel-like layout.

The following Swift 5.1 sample code shows a possible implementation of `UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout` in order to have the layout you want:

*CollectionView.swift*

```swift
import UIKit

class CollectionView: UICollectionView {

    override var safeAreaInsets: UIEdgeInsets {
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: super.safeAreaInsets.top, left: 0, bottom: super.safeAreaInsets.bottom, right: 0)
    }

}
```

*ViewController.swift*

```swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var collectionView: CollectionView!
    var dataSource: UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<Int, Int>!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        navigationItem.title = "Collection view"

        // Compositional layout

        let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout(sectionProvider: {
            (sectionIndex: Int, layoutEnvironment: NSCollectionLayoutEnvironment) -> NSCollectionLayoutSection? in

            let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1), heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1))
            let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)
            item.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 5, leading: 5, bottom: 5, trailing: 5)

            let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalHeight(1), heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1))
            let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: groupSize, subitems: [item])

            let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
            section.orthogonalScrollingBehavior = UICollectionLayoutSectionOrthogonalScrollingBehavior.groupPagingCentered

            return section
        })

        // Set collection view

        collectionView = CollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .systemGroupedBackground
        collectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        collectionView.register(Cell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")

        // View layout

        view.addSubview(collectionView)

        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        collectionView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 160).isActive = true
        collectionView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true

        // Collection view diffable data source

        dataSource = UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<Int, Int>(collectionView: collectionView, cellProvider: {
            (collectionView: UICollectionView, indexPath: IndexPath, identifier: Int) -> UICollectionViewCell? in

            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! Cell
            return cell
        })

        var snapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<Int, Int>()
        snapshot.appendSections([0])
        snapshot.appendItems(Array(0 ..< 5))
        dataSource.apply(snapshot, animatingDifferences: false)
    }

}
```

*Cell.swift*

```swift
import UIKit

class Cell: UICollectionViewCell {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        contentView.backgroundColor = .orange
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("not implemnted")
    }

}
```

---

### #2. Using `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`

If you're targeting a lower version of iOS than iOS 13, you can subclass [`UICollectionViewFlowLayout`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewflowlayout), compute the horizontal insets in [`prepare()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewlayout/1617752-prepare) and implement [`targetContentOffset(forProposedContentOffset:withScrollingVelocity:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewlayout/1617729-targetcontentoffset) in order to force the cell to be centered after user scroll.

The following Swift 5.1 sample code shows how to implement the subclass of `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`:

*ViewController.swift*

```swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let flowLayout = PaggedFlowLayout()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        navigationItem.title = "Collection view"

        let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: flowLayout)
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .systemGroupedBackground
        collectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        collectionView.decelerationRate = .fast
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
        collectionView.register(Cell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")

        view.addSubview(collectionView)
        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        collectionView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 160).isActive = true
        collectionView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    }

}
```

```swift
extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 9
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! Cell
        return cell
    }

}
```

*PaggedFlowLayout.swift*

```swift
import UIKit

class PaggedFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

    override init() {
        super.init()

        scrollDirection = .horizontal
        minimumLineSpacing = 5
        minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
        sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 5, bottom: 5, right: 5)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func prepare() {
        super.prepare()

        guard let collectionView = collectionView else { fatalError() }

        // itemSize
        let itemHeight = collectionView.bounds.height - sectionInset.top - sectionInset.bottom
        itemSize = CGSize(width: itemHeight, height: itemHeight)

        // horizontal insets
        let horizontalInsets = (collectionView.bounds.width - itemSize.width) / 2
        sectionInset.left = horizontalInsets
        sectionInset.right = horizontalInsets
    }

    /*
     Add some snapping behaviour to center the cell after scrolling.
     Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14291208/1966109
     */
    override func targetContentOffset(forProposedContentOffset proposedContentOffset: CGPoint, withScrollingVelocity velocity: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
        guard let collectionView = collectionView else { return .zero }

        var proposedContentOffset = proposedContentOffset
        var offsetAdjustment = CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude
        let horizontalCenter = proposedContentOffset.x + collectionView.bounds.size.width / 2
        let targetRect = CGRect(x: proposedContentOffset.x, y: 0, width: collectionView.bounds.size.width, height: collectionView.bounds.size.height)

        guard let layoutAttributesArray = super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: targetRect) else { return .zero }

        for layoutAttributes in layoutAttributesArray {
            let itemHorizontalCenter = layoutAttributes.center.x
            if abs(itemHorizontalCenter - horizontalCenter) < abs(offsetAdjustment) {
                offsetAdjustment = itemHorizontalCenter - horizontalCenter
            }
        }

        var nextOffset = proposedContentOffset.x + offsetAdjustment
        let snapStep = itemSize.width + minimumLineSpacing

        func isValidOffset(_ offset: CGFloat) -> Bool {
            let minContentOffset = -collectionView.contentInset.left
            let maxContentOffset = collectionView.contentInset.left + collectionView.contentSize.width - itemSize.width
            return offset >= minContentOffset && offset <= maxContentOffset
        }

        repeat {
            proposedContentOffset.x = nextOffset
            let deltaX = proposedContentOffset.x - collectionView.contentOffset.x
            let velX = velocity.x

            if deltaX.sign.rawValue * velX.sign.rawValue != -1 {
                break
            }

            nextOffset += CGFloat(velocity.x.sign.rawValue) * snapStep
        } while isValidOffset(nextOffset)

        return proposedContentOffset
    }

}
```

*Cell.swift*

```swift
import UIKit

class Cell: UICollectionViewCell {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        contentView.backgroundColor = .orange
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("not implemnted")
    }

}
```

---

Display on iPhone 11 Pro Max:

[image]