# Horizontal Pagination in CollectionView Like in iPhone Camera (Video/SlowMo/Photo/etc)

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewflowlayout

I have tried this solution and many others. It isn't the same as in **iPhone Camera** (Reference Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fyFW.jpg).
Center selection with pagination of one cell not by visible rows.

[Paging UICollectionView by cells, not screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22895465/paging-uicollectionview-by-cells-not-screen)

This solution helps me creating center selection with pagination but it flicker also drags a lot.

https://gist.github.com/vinhnx/fb20c6942b5823df1c35e69850caf9f6

Need help!! Creating **UICollectionView** **Pagination** by **Visble Cell** with **Centered Selection** like **iPhone Camera**.