# UICollectionView pagination works even if we don't set it

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

The question is about testing UICollectionView pagination. So by the default I don't see any code that use `setPagingEnabled` in the project. The collection view was made from the code. There is no xibs or storybaords in the project.

But collection view has pagination and very low horizontal scroll. I have no idea from where it can be configured.

Maybe there is some injection in code or category or something like swizzling I don't know. Any suggestion from where pagination was set?

Comment: I would guess the view's dimension is not set properly.

Comment: @DinoTw i found this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13492037/targetcontentoffsetforproposedcontentoffsetwithscrollingvelocity-without-subcla) and it's connected to my question