# UICollectionView clipsToBounds is not working properly with paging

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, paging

I am using UICollectionView with horizontal paging enabled. 
My collectionView frame is less than the screen size.

I used the following code :

```
myCollectionView.clipsToBounds=FALSE;
```

Still I am not able to see the views outside the bounds of my collectionView.
I am using custom `UICollectionViewLayout`

Answer (score 6):

If the size of each page is greater or equal to your `collectionView`'s frame size, you will not be able to see the content outside the frame even `clipToBounds` is disabled.

In order to save the memory, the cells in the `collectionView` are reusable and will be removed if they are out of the frame (i.e. only shows the *visible* cells).

To recreate the effects like the one seen on the App Store:

[image]

Try to set the frame of the `collectionView` as large as your `collectionView`'s `superView`, and specify proper `minimumLineSpacing` for your `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`.

You may like to take a look at this post about [`targetContentOffsetForProposedContentOffset:withScrollingVelocity`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13493707/2695329) which gives you controls to decide the `contentOffset` of a given page.

Comment: Great answer! Keep it up.

Comment: For this you should also set `collectionView.contentInset` so that the first and last cells can be centered. I found this answer to be particularly helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38648516/4139760

Answer (score -3):

I'm not sure but may be the problem when you init your collectionView it's initializing with the some default settings like clipToBounds. Try this method to layout subviews:

```
-(void)layoutSubviews{
   [super layoutSubviews];
   myCollectionView.clipsToBounds = FALSE;
}
```

Hope it works.