# Tvos UICollectionView ; no paging

Tags: uicollectionview, tvos

doesn't the appleTvOs support paging on UICollectionView??I have a full screen collection view which i want to display image galleries as items.My problem is that when i swipe on the remote, it scrolles down to the last slide.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13492037/targetcontentoffsetforproposedcontentoffsetwithscrollingvelocity-without-subcla

Answer (score 1):

As of ios 10.2 / XCode 8.3, it seems UICollectionView on tvOS actually supports paging only if you set it via storyboard/xib. Still, there's no support (yet?) for `isPagingEnabled` in code. Probably a bug?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment (tvOS 10.2) UICollectionView does not support paging. The property `isPagingEnabled` of UIScrollView is not available for tvOS.

As you can see in the following link, this property is only available in the iOS SDK
https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiscrollview/1619432-ispagingenabled

An alternative solution to build an image gallery like the one you described could be to use UIPageViewController, with paging support out of the box for tvOS.