# UICollectionView like Facebook friend request UI

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I'm trying to make a `UICollectionView` with horizontal scrolling and paging like Facebook's friend request UI. [GIFV LINK](https://i.imgur.com/XDJ0OUb.gifv). 
*All the requests in this video are from fake profiles, so no worries about privacy.*

I don't understand how I make them not full-screen, and still centered. I played around with offset, inset and sizing, but I just get it like this, where the offset grows every scroll. 
[image]

How do I keep the page

- Less than max width
- Centered
- Showing a hint of the next and previous page

Like Facebook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This a little bit tricky.

You'll need to turn off paging and use [`targetContentOffsetForProposedContentOffset:withScrollingVelocity`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13492037/targetcontentoffsetforproposedcontentoffsetwithscrollingvelocity-without-subcla/13493707#13493707) to control the offset.

Edit: I made a simple example [here](https://github.com/notcyhsutw/collectionview-paging).