# Set position of first and last UICollectionViewCell at centre of UICollectionView

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a requirement in which the collection view should start at the centre of the screen and when I start scrolling, it should scroll to the left end. Also the last cell should scroll to the centre. If it is confusing please refer the images: **My Current state:**

[image: My Current State]

**What I want at initial stage:**

[image: InitialStage]

**Also at the end of scrolling:**

[image: End of scrolling]

I played with content offset a little but no success so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content offset is the amount that the collection view (or actually the scroll view behind it) is currently scrolled.

What you are looking for is the `contentInset`.

You should be able to change this through the `UICollectionViewLayout` object that you are using. If you are using a `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` then it has a property for `sectionInset`.

If you do something like...

```
layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: screenWidth * 0.5, bottom: 0, right: screenWidth * 0.5)
```

It should get you something like what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you. Works just as expected.

Comment: Can I add pagination like the cell should automatically fit at the centre point? Now it is like I can set the space between 4 & 5 at the centre, which is not good

Comment: @Arun Pagination only works where the page is the full width of the scroll view. But you could override the `contentOffsetForProposedContentOffset...` method. One sec, will get a link.

Comment: @Arun https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13492037/targetcontentoffsetforproposedcontentoffsetwithscrollingvelocity-without-subcla/13493707#13493707 It's in Objective-C but will give you an idea of what you need to do.